# Index of intersection of two normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Question:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroup of $G$.
>    If $[G:H]=2$ and $[G:K]=3$, determine $[G:H∩K]$.

My attempt:
I think $[G:H∩K] = 6$. 
Since $G$, $H$, $K$ are finite, let $|G| = 6n$, $|H| = 3n$, $|K| = 2n$.

By Lagrange theorem, $|H∩K|$ divides $n $ ($H∩K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$).

If $n$ divides $|H∩K|$, (or $n$ is lower bound of $|H∩K|$)
then $|H∩K|=n$, it leads to $[G:H∩K] = 6$.

But I don't know how to show $n$ divides $|H∩K|$.

Normality of $H$ and $K$ is not used yet and I have a trouble with using this fact.

Need help! Thanks.

Comment: @sqtrat Oh, I missed it! I assumed that n is a positve integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the second isomorphism theorem, we have 
$$\dfrac{HK}{H}\cong \dfrac{K}{H\cap K}$$
and thus $$|H\cap K|=\frac{|H|\cdot|K| }{|HK|}\geq \frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|G|}=\frac{6n^2}{6n}=n.$$

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $M, N \unlhd G$, with gcd$(|G:M|,|G:N|)=1$, then $G=MN$, and $|G:M \cap N|=|G:M| \cdot |G:N|$. Proof: the index of the subgroup $MN$ divides both indices of $M$ and $N$. Now apply the second isomorphism theorem.

The result is still true when you drop normality on $M$ or $N$.

Comment: Thank you! Does 'Drop normality on M or N' mean either M or N, but not both of them?

Comment: One of them or both! So the mathematical "or" so to speak.

Comment: @Jay Lee: I forgot to tell you that if they are both non normal, you cannot apply the 2nd isomorphism theorem, and the proof as I sketched above will be be different (a counting argument): in fact if $M$ and $N$ are just subgroups, then $x(M \cap N) \mapsto xN$ defines an injection from the cosets of $M \cap N$ in $M$ to the cosets of $N$ in $G$. Hence $|M:M \cap N| \leq |G:N|$. Which implies $|G:M \cap N| \leq |G:M| \cdot |G:N|$. The opposite inequality follows from the indices in $G$ of $M$ and $N$ being relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Note that $$[G:H\cap K]= [G:H][H:H\cap K]=2[H:H\cap K]$$ and 
$$[G:H\cap K]= [G:K][K:H\cap K]=3[H:H\cap K].$$
Since both $2$ and $3$ divides $[G:H\cap K],$ $6$ does as well. 
Since $|H\cap K|$ divides both $|H|, |K|$ and $|G|$, it follows that there is an integer $n$ such that $|G|=6n$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please give me more hint?

Comment: See Arnaud D.'s answer, it is probably much quicker to see, from what you have already done.